# (Network error while fetching https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/puma-3.8.1.gemspec.rz)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

me sale este error al momento de ejecutar bundle install, soy nuevo en rails primera vez que me sales to: Network error while fetching https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/puma-3.8.1.gemspec.rz

Comment: De verdad tienes acceso al archivo desde el computador? prueba a descargarlo desde el navegador. Quizás fue un error de red puntual y podrías intentar nuevamente

Comment: soy nuevo en rails

Comment: primera vez que me pasa eso

Answer (score 0):

Tienes problemas con instalar puma revisa que pasa con esa gema, si estas en windows te recomiendo migrar a linux sino tendras muchos problemas de este tipo, reinstala ruby y luego rails tras esto hacer el rails new proyecto entrar ahi y hacer el bundle install

Comment: no amigo no utilizo windows, utilizo debian

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
gem install bundler
bundle update
```

Si no funciona:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle
```

Si todavía no funciona revisa el Gemfile, estará indicando una versión de puma que ya no existe o algo así, intenta dejar esa línea en simplemente:

```
gem 'puma'
```

Otros consejos pasarían por instalar rvm si no lo tienes y asegurarte de que estás usando la versión necesaria de ruby:

```
rvm list
```

Posiblemente tu gemfile indique una versión en concreto y rvm la seleccionaría automáticamente al entrar en el directorio. Caso contrario puedes tú decirle a rvm que por defecto utilice la recomendada por la aplicación.